# mobile intel GM45 ubuntu support

Tags: laptop

I have a very old laptop with intel pentium t4400, 2 GB ddr2 ram, gma 4500mhd (mobile intel gm45), but currently there's no hard drive on this laptop. I wonder how if I install ubuntu on this machine (for simple browsing, typing on google docs), should I install the latest version of Ubuntu or the older one? and is it bottleneck or overkill if I put ssd on this machine ?

Comment: I've used a `lenovo thinkpad sl510 (c2d-t6570, 2gb ram, i915)` to QA-test almost all releases & most *flavors* of Ubuntu in the past few years; but Id consider many other things beyond just machine in what I'd use. I'd suggest a *lighter flavor* where the desktop will match your intended apps given the limited (2GB) of RAM.  A lot more details than you provided would determine what I'd install & use.

Comment: You can give Xubuntu 20.04 a try. If it is too slow, stick with something like Lubuntu 18.04  with the latest version of your favorite browser (You can use snap or flatpak to get the latest version of browser. Although this flavor is out of support, the base packages still get security updates as they are common with Ubuntu 18.04, and you should not encounter any malware if you use it carefully).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [Debian LXDE](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/) (which is not supported on this site). It still runs quite well on Raspberry Pis with 1 GB RAM or less. Debian 11 will be [supported](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) until 2026, and Debian 10, until 2024.